# suid script not working correctly

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, setuid

My os is Fedora 24 and I tried to test the suid bit functionality.

I wrote below bash as Setuid.bash:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ $USER = 'root' ]
then
    echo "Like Root Run"
    echo "Root User Add in " $(date) >> /etc/SetUid
else
    echo "Other User Run"
    echo $USER "User Add in " $(date) >> /etc/SetUid
fi
```

with `-rwsrw-r-x. 1 root root 249 May 21 14:45 /bin/Setuid.bash` permission and `-rwx------. 1 root root 432 May 21 14:45 /etc/SetUid`

Now, when I tried `/bin/Setuid.bash` as root I got:

> Like Root Run

but when run that with *Test* user I encountered:

> Other User Run
>
> bin/Setuid.bash: line 8: /etc/SetUid: Permission denied

I'll appreciate if any one let me know, where is my way wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Long time ago, `bash` (and other shell interpreters) have added built-in security measures against suid (ab)use because it is/was dangerous. [Dangers of SUID Shell Scripts](http://www.drdobbs.com/dangers-of-suid-shell-scripts/199101190)

From [Why Bash is like that: suid](https://www.vidarholen.net/contents/blog/?p=30)

> Bash scripts can’t run with the suid bit set. First of all, Linux
> doesn’t allow any scripts to be setuid, though some other OS do.
> Second, bash will detect being run as setuid, and immediately drop the
> privileges.
>
> This is because shell script security is extremely dependent on the
> environment, much more so than regular C apps.

Ultimately, nowadays the suid bit is mostly useful for executable binaries. A way of running a script/bash like that is invoking it from a suid compiled binary.

Comment: thanks man for the answer, but when I can use this option?

Comment: added to the answer.

Comment: _that is invoking it from a suid compiled binary_ you meant I should use a binary file to get the correct answer?

Comment: Yes, for instance writing in C  a wrapper that calls bash http://stackoverflow.com/questions/556194/calling-a-script-from-a-setuid-root-c-program-script-does-not-run-as-root

Comment: You only refer to the Bash shell.  No  suid applies to any shell script - not just the Bash shell.

Comment: @fpmurphy1 The question was about the Bash shell, and I agree with you. Coincidentally, the bash shell binary was one of the first shells dropping setuid privileges, if not the first.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro.  It is the kernel that controls setuid privileges - not a shell.  4.3BSD (Tahoe) was probably the first major OS to disable setuid for shell scripts.

Comment: @fpmurphy1 Now that you talk I do remember that FreeBSD kernel indeed does that...however bash does it too. http://hmarco.org/bugs/bash_4.3-setuid-bug.html