# How can I verify that a file is being execute as root account?

Tags: linux, root, suid

Let's say we have created a file with root account with `-rwsr-xr-x script.sh` permissions. We have set suid bit on this file so any user who is gonna execute this file, it's gonna be execute by owner of the file which is root. For example let's look at the `passwd` command:

```
$ ls -l /usr/bin/passwd
-rwsr-xr-x 1 root root 68208 Apr 16 17:06 /usr/bin/passwd
```

This command is similar to our file. Any user who executes this command, it's going to be run as root account no matter if the user is root or has sudo privileges.

The question is how can i verify this subject?

To figure this out I'v tried this: if we look at `script.sh` contents, I'v wrote this simple script:

```
#!/bin/bash 

if [[ $UID -eq 0 ]]
then 
    echo "Running as root"
else
    echo "Not root"
fi
```

now if I run this script as a regular user, the output will be: `Not root`

So how can I check if it's running as root?

---

Please let me know if I have misunderstanding of the concepts. I'm a newbie.

Comment: bash script is run by /bin/bash, which is not suid root binary.

Comment: See [suid script not working correctly](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/366365/suid-script-not-working-correctly)

Comment: See: [Allow setuid on shell scripts](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/364/allow-setuid-on-shell-scripts)

Comment: I got that, thank you guys.

Comment: I normally do a check like   `if [ -w /etc/passwd ]`...  if you can write to that file then you're either root or the whole system can be compromised :-)

Comment: Don't depend on environment variables (`$UID`), they're subject to manipulation. Rather, read `man id` and use `id -u` to get the UID.

Answer (score 0):

What about trying something like:

```
if [ $(whoami) = "root" ]
```